# why this code fail to sign up on firebase?

Tags: firebase

For some reason this code fail to sign up on firebase,

```
app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
  const newUser = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword,
    handle: req.body.handle
  }

  let token, userId;
  db.doc(`/users/${newUser.handle}`).get().then(doc => {
    if (doc.exists) {
      return res.status(400).json({ handle: 'this handle already exists' })
    } else {
      return firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password)
    }
  })
    .then(data => {
      userId = data.user.uid;
      return data.user.getIdToken();
    })
    .then(idToken => {
      token = idToken;
      const userCredentials = {
        handle: newUser.handle,
        email: newUser.email,
        createdAt: new date().toISOString(),
        userId
      }

      return db.doc(`/users/${newUser.handle}`).set(userCredentials)
    })
    .then(() => {
      return res.status(201).json({ token });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if (err.code === "auth/email-already-in-use") {
        return res.status(400).json({ email: 'Email is alrready in use' })
      } else {
        return res.status(500).json({ general: 'something went wrong, please try again' })
      }
    })
});
```

I always get `{ general: 'something went wrong, please try again' }` , i am using postman to mimic the request to firebase,

This code works perfectly:

```
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password)
    .then(data => {
      return data.user.getIdToken();
    })
    .then(token => {
     return res.status(201).json({token})
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).json({error: 'something went wrongly'})
    })
```

The first trial is from a tutorial i am following in Youtube and sadly it doesn't work

Comment: It is a little unclear what tech stack are you using. Is it frontend code? Which framework are you using?

Comment: Also, try logging `err.code`

Comment: it is firebase cloud functions @frunkad

Comment: Firebase Admin SDK does not have a SignIn function

Comment: @frunkad my bad , sorry it seems,it is ```createUserWithEmailAndPassword ``` not ```signInWithEmailAndPassword```, will fix it

Comment: @frunkad it seems that was the problem, thank you, everything solved now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the backend, you can use [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin) to get details about any user but it does not have any ability to *login on behalf of user*.